# segmented control leads to pincolor changes in mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

the problem is this:

I have a mapkit view with 2 different colors pinpoint. Now i have added in a segmented control to display different map types ie. satellite, standard and hybrid. When my application loads, its correct with 2 different colors. However, when i select the segments, all my pinpoints will change to red colour.

Is there a way to reload all my data and pinpoints such that every segment will give me the same initial view??

```
- (IBAction) segmentAction:(id)sender 
    {
    UISegmentedControl* segCtl = sender ;

    if( [segCtl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0 )
    { 
        NSLog(@"first view");
        _mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;

    }
    if( [segCtl selectedSegmentIndex] == 1 ) 
    { 
        NSLog(@"2nd view");
        _mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeSatellite;

    }
    if( [segCtl selectedSegmentIndex] == 2 ) 
    {

        NSLog(@"3rd view");
        _mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your map view controller implements the viewForAnnotation: method - if this is missing, the pin colors might get reset if the view is refreshed. For example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"redpin"] autorelease];
newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
return newAnnotation;
}
```

Comment: hi nick.. thx for the help.. i have those already.. but my pincolour are still changing whenever i select a different segment. Is there a way to reload the map again for every segment?

Comment: When you instantiate MKPinAnnotationView, do you use autorelease? I edited to include that. Maybe that will help?

Comment: also, if you are using your own custom image, make sure you use MKAnnotationView and not MKPinAnnotationView

Comment: yea had that too.. =(

juz dun get it why the colors keep changing... hence i will have to press another tab in my tabBar then b to the map tab before the colours are right again... the segment control changes all pinpoints to red

Comment: thanks Nick! indeed it was the MKAnnotationView... lol... didnt know why when it first loaded it allowed me to use MKPinAnnotationView even though mine was custom image...

thanks for the help again!